# How to Set Viewing Permissions on a Calendar

Tags: 2010, permissions

I have created a new calendar and named it 'Management'. I am trying to set it so only a few employees can view and edit it, and do not want it visible for people who do not have permission to use it.

The problem is I cannot find anywhere in SharePoint where I can set viewing/editing/etc. permissions for the calendar.

If someone can direct me it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A calendar is a list in sharepoint like everything else.  As such, you can set permissions on it.  Simply go to the calendar, look in the ribbon and select 'Calendar' then 'List Settings' then 'Permissions for this list'.  from there you can define the permissions as you see fit.

Comment: The 'Permissions for this list' does not exist under 'List Settings' for me. I have plenty of other options, but none related to permissions. Under 'Permissions and Management' I have 'Delete this list', 'Save list as template' and 'Workflow' Settings'. My account is added in SharePoint group 'Farm Administrators' as well.

Comment: You need to have high enough permissions, which usually means Full Control at the site collection.  How you get that depends on your specific farm.

Comment: Also, being in the Farm Administrators group typically means nothing when looking at a specific site unless that group is granted higher permissions via Web Application Policy

Comment: This is strange as a "Check Permissions" on my account says I have "Full Control". To be clear this is a single server of SharePoint 2010, and I am the administrator. I am in the process of setting it up to look at use in our small office.

Comment: Alright I am starting to get confused now. When I browse the site via http://servername:20701 I get totally different options vs under http://companyweb even though I am under the same user account. The changes I make under the servername:20701 do not appear under companyweb in regards to users/permissions/groups.

Comment: Do 'companyweb' and 'servername:20701' share the same content database?  If not, then I would not expect the changes in one to affect the other.  Bear in mind that every site collection has its own security that is completely independent of the Farm Administrators group

Comment: Yes they share the same database and DNS points them to the same server. They are one and the same. Many more options appear under companyweb. I added my account under 'CompanyWeb Owners' which only exists under companyweb options and not servername:20701 and now have full control. It just appears that I was making changes in the wrong place.

Comment: The way you describe this it really sounds like you have two different content databases in the mix.  A quick way to tell is to upload a document to a document library on one then go into the other and see if the uploaded document is there. I'm going to bet that it won't be.